# CoralDraw(.cdr) file decoding online

Tags: php, asp.net, flash

I am going to develop website like pixlr.cm or vistaprint.com , I have problem in devlopng while working with coral draw files, I want to make and option to import coral draw files and allow editing on that files, but problem arise when i am going to use that filesbecause coral draw files are not jpg or png formate they all are as layer image like photoshop and without dpi pixels, So 
can anyone suggest me how i can play with all coral draw files?
Your guidance will help me a lot

Thanks

Comment: It is **Corel** Draw. And it's a vector graphic, which is majorly different from "jpg or png"

Comment: Yes then which option should i go with?

Comment: Depends. What do you want to do with them?

Comment: I want to give flexibility to user that they can modify and edit those cdr files and re-save in same format